# AndroidDebugKey Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Tags: java, android, google-maps, keystore, keytool

Whenever I enter in the terminal:

keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
-storepass android -keypass android

It asks me for a password. I've never set a password before. I've read somewhere else to put in "android" but I still receive the following error:

keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Also I am new to the Mac environment. Whenever I type in the password the cursor does not move. I'm not sure if this is default Mac behavior for concealing passwords or if the password is just not registering so that's why I get the error. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

This command works for me:

```
keytool -list -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

**And the password is android.** It will list your aliases and you can copy and paste as you please. I guess you're using it for debugging the maps.

Comment: Your command works. Thank you. I am just learning to work with the maps.

Comment: +1 for saying the password! That's all I needed XD

Comment: keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist where is key tool located

Answer (score 2):

This was also a problem for me, but it wasn't the command that was the problem, it was that I was entering my user password and not the android password which is "android" at the prompt.