# Could not list certificates in keystore. Probably because the password was incorrect

Tags: android, android-keystore, calabash-android

I am running calabash-android in a docker file and when I run the calabash test I got the error

```
/usr/local/bundle/gems/calabash-android-0.7.2/lib/calabash-android/java_keystore.rb:6:in `initialize': No such keystore file '/home/core/Android/debug.keystore' (RuntimeError)
```

I have tried this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771210/androiddebugkey-keystore-was-tampered-with-or-password-was-incorrect) and not working for me.

**Edit**

After setting up the path the error is like

```
/lib/calabash-android/java_keystore‌​.rb:32:in `initialize': Could not list certificates in keystore. Probably because the password was incorrect. (RuntimeError)
```

Comment: Did you deleted your default keystore ie "debug.keystore"..Just check if it's still there.. You can find it usually here  "C:\Users\username\.android"

Comment: Actually I am running it from docker and it is available there. After setting up the path I got the error /usr/local/bundle/gems/calabash-android-0.7.2/lib/calabash-android/java_keystore.rb:32:in `initialize': Could not list certificates in keystore. Probably because the password was incorrect. (RuntimeError)

Comment: May be you have to set the password as well along with the path to keystore.... I don't know what this "calabash" is .

Comment: It is an automated testing tool for android app. I have set the keystore path in it. I have set it like {"keystore_location":"/home/core/Android/debug.keystore","keystore_password":"android","keystore_alias":"androiddebugkey"}

Comment: And it was working for me in my local with the same apk and debug.keystore file.

Comment: Hmm ok ,.Sry man I have no idea..

Comment: That's ok. Thanks for the try. :)

Comment: try to delete .calabash_settings file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be fixed by navigating to the **/.android** directory and remove the debug.keystore file if exist one and go try the command

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

And following that navigate to the directory where the feature files exist and setup the calabash android by using the command

```
calabash-android setup
```

The resign the new debug.keystore file using the command

```
calabash-android resign <apk path>
```

And finally we can run the test by using the command

```
calabash-android run <apk path>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an interesting thing to note. If your keystore password has `$`, then you need to escape it in `.calabash_settings` file.

Look at the content of this file:

`{"keystore_location":"my-release-keystore.jks","keystore_password":"abc$123","keystore_alias":"MyAlias"}`

If you leave "abc$123" like this, you should get an error. Then you should escape the password like the following example:

`{"keystore_location":"my-release-keystore.jks","keystore_password":"abc\\$123","keystore_alias":"MyAlias"}`

Take a look at **\\** for escaping special characters.