# Android Studio Generate Signed Failed to read key

Tags: android, gradle, android-keystore, apktool

I have faced a quite serious issue with my keystore and failed to resolve it.

I'm using:

```
-androind studio 3.0.1 
-gradle:3.0.1
-distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

and for some reason when I try to 
`Build> Generate Signed Apk...`

I'm getting

`Error:Execution failed for task :app:packageProductionRelease.
Failed to read key myKey from store "C:\Users\abc\Documents\bucket\mm\keystore": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect`

I've tried using terminal

`keytool -list -v -keystore "keystore.jks"  -alias myKey -storepass pass -keypass pass`

and it shows the key's properties. so Im pretty sure the password is correct and the keystore is not corrupted.

Is there an alternative way or a solution to resolve this issue ?

your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891182/keytool-error-keystore-was-tampered-with-or-password-was-incorrect

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AndroidDebugKey Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771210/androiddebugkey-keystore-was-tampered-with-or-password-was-incorrect)

Comment: @2Dee we are using our own keystore and it's for release. It is not similar to what you suggest

Comment: @Jay Rathod im using an existing keystore. So it is not similar to the SO post you are suggesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone faces the similar issue. apparently there was genuinely an issue with the keystore. after replacing it with and old copy of the same keystore it worked.

Comment: could you give more details? : )

Comment: It's been a long time so I don't recall the details. but the conclusion was that the key was somehow corrupted. After replacing it using a copy of backup it resolved everything